# Lexical Editor with react to detect word postion

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lexical, lexical-editor

I'm trying to use Lexical editor with react to implement a text editor "similar to the Grammarly concept" to send each typed word with its index on socket.

I need to know what is the best way to implement it considering if user change specific word at the middle of the sentence how I could detect its position?